# Create multidimensional arry without identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use a multidimensional arry in JS. The array looks like this:

```
var name = {
  abc: {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
  }
};
```

This works like a charm. But is it possible to create the same array without the numbers? Like this:

```
var name = {
  abc: {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
  }
};
```

I still need the same access to it (e.q. name['abc'][1] = b)

Comment: What you have is plain objects not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an actual array instead of an object for `abc`?

```
var name = {
  abc: [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
  ]
};
```

Comment: Good idea, but how can I access the array using `name['abc'][1]`?

Comment: Exactly like that. That'll give you the `b` element. If this is on the top level, don't use the `name` variable, because that can only be a string - use a different variable name.